# Redirecting http traffic to https for my site, including subdomains

Tags: .htaccess, ssl, redirect, subdomain

Getting my wildcard SSL certificate to run was already a challenge but it turns out that redirecting the http traffic to https is even more difficult.
I need to redirect http://example.com, http://www.example.com, [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) to https://example.com.
Additionally, http://subdomain1.example.com should redirect to https://subdomain1.example.com (I have a list of 7 subdomains).
My current .htaccess doesn't do the trick:
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
I'm also confused as to whether I need to leave port 80 open to enable the redirect.
I would be immensely grateful for any help.

Comment: If you don't leave port 80 open you'll never make the initial connection that you're trying to redirect.

Comment: That's what I thought. It's open.